# How to debug custom minion block which is inside IPendingOrdersMinionPipeline?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have replaced default ReleaseOrderBlock with CustomBlock inside IPendingOrdersMinionPipeline. I have tried debugging by stopping CommerceAuthoring_Sc9 in IIS and running Commerce engine on port 5000 using IISExpress in Visual studio.But debugger is not hitting to Custom block inside plugin. However i am able to debug other plugins.

Comment: did you bootstrap your commerce engine after you made changes ?

Comment: can you add here your configsitecore file where you replace ReleaseOrderBlock?

Comment: @VladIobagiu : Yes. I have bootstraped commerce engine. 
Below is the code block where replacing Minion block:
services.Sitecore().Pipelines(
                                pipeLineConfig =>
                                pipeLineConfig.ConfigurePipeline<IPendingOrdersMinionPipeline>(
                                    config => config.Replace<ReleaseOrderBlock, SendOrderToOmsMinionBlock>()
                                                    ));

Comment: Could it be that the pipeline is aborting before it gets to your block?

Comment: Did you create your plugin inside the `Customer.Sample.Solution` solution and added a reference in the `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine` project to your new plugin project. After I did that, I was able to debug my plugin, when I hit F5 and ran the engine in IIS Express.

Comment: You should also make sure, that the `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine` project runs the Minion environment and not the Authoring environment. This in configured in the `wwwroot/config.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CommerceMinions_Sc9` is responsible for run and call all OrdersMinions like `ReleasedOrdersMinion`, `WaitingForAvailabilityOrdersMinion` and etc.

If you want to check your changes in CommerceAuthoring role, you need to change Environment variable `MinionsHost` in Postman to `{{Protocol}}://{{HostName}}:5000` and execute `Run PendingOrders Minion` request from Postman manually

Comment: After running Run PendingOrders Minion from postman Habitat environment, am able to debug the plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check these three things :

1) You have added your block to the pipeline correctly using the `ConfigureSitecore` class (I sometimes think its correct but miss something small)

2) Make sure you are referencing your new plugin assembly from the Sitecore.Commerce.Engine project

3) Look at the latest `NodeConfigurationXXXXX.log` and ensure that your block is registered in the correct pipeline. You could also use the `{{ServiceHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/GetPipelines()` call in postman.

You can also ensure the minions are actually running by executing the correct postman call e.g. `{{MinionsHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/RunMinion()`

Comment: Block is configured correctly. Block name is verifed in Node logs. I had added logs info which can also be seen SCF logs. IPending minion is picking up orders in pending state after like 5 min interval. But i am curious to debugging this minion block in visual studio to understand it better.

Comment: Have you tried running the engine in the console rather than IISExpress? You can do this by using "engine" option to start the engine.